# Does the .NET spec specify how constructor constraints should be used?

Tags: .net, generics, constructor

I've been having a looksie at the .NET CLI spec, and although it mentions you can have a default constructor constraint on a generic type paramter, it doesn't specify anything you can then *do* with such a generic type to actually create it. What's the official 'spec' way of actually creating an instance of a generic type with a constructor constraint?

Comment: Do you mean the C# spec or the CLI spec?

Comment: The CLI spec. There's no mention of what you do with a `ctor` constraint in IL.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
public static void CreateThings<T>() where T : new() {
    T t = new T();
    // now either return t or do other things with it, particularly
    // when combined with interface constraints
}
```

To quote the spec sections from ECMA 334 v4

### 14.5.10.1 Object creation expressions

> The type of an
> object-creation-expression shall be a
> class-type, a value-type, or a
> type-parameter having the
> constructor-constraint or the value
> type constraint (§25.7).

...

> Otherwise, if T is a type-parameter:
>
> - If A is present, a compile-time error
>   occurs.
> - Otherwise, if T has the
>   constructor-constraint or the value
>   type constraint, the result of the
>   objectcreation- expression is a value
>   of type T.
> - Otherwise, the
>   object-creation-expression is invalid,
>   and a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: I'm looking for what you do with it in IL per the spec

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor in the generic type:

```
return new T();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a *default* constructor constraint, it's a *parameterless* constructor constraint. The class has to have a parameterless constructor, regardless if that constructor is the implicitly created default constructor or an explicitly declared parameterless constructor.

Both of these classes fulfill the constraint:

```
public class A {
}

public class B {
  public B() { }
}
```

But not this one, as there is no implicitly created constructor if you have any explicitly declared constructors:

```
public class C {
  public C(int id) { }
}
```

As it's a parameterless constructor, there is only one way to use it:

```
T item = new T();
```

It's odd if there is no mention of that in the spec, but it's at least clearly described in MS's C# reference: [new Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28VS.80%29.aspx). A spec is however not meant to be read ion the same way as documentation, so it might be hard to find exactly where it's mentioned, and it might only be mentioned once.

Comment: I know how to use it in C#, I want to know if there's any 'standard' way of using it in IL